# How to use two filters in stream for different transformations

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to perform transformations only for a particular condition.
I do this transformation:

```
// filter 1: less date - group by max date by groupId
        List<Info> listResult = new ArrayList<>(listInfo.stream()
                .filter(info -> info.getDate().getTime() < date.getTime())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Info::getGroupId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.reducing((Info i1, Info i2) -> i1.getDate().getTime() > i2.getDate().getTime() ? i1 : i2),
                        Optional::get))).values());
```

But for the condition when there is more than the specified date, I do not need to convert anything, I just need to return this data:

```
// filter 2: more date - nothing change in list
        List<Info> listMoreByDate = listInfo.stream()
                .filter(info -> info.getDate().getTime() >= date.getTime())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Next, to combine these two filters - I combine the two lists:

```
listResult.addAll(listMoreByDate);
```

My question is, can this be done in one stream? Because filter 2 is absolutely useless, it simply returns a list for this condition.

Is it possible to perform these transformations with one continuous expression?

My full code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Info info1 = new Info(1L, getDateFromStr("2018-02-02T10:00:00"), 3L);
        Info info2 = new Info(2L, getDateFromStr("2018-02-02T12:00:00"), 3L);
        Info info3 = new Info(3L, getDateFromStr("2018-02-05T12:00:00"), 6L);
        Info info4 = new Info(4L, getDateFromStr("2018-02-05T10:00:00"), 6L);

        Date date = getDateFromStr("2018-02-03T10:10:10");

        List<Info> listInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        listInfo.add(info1);
        listInfo.add(info2);
        listInfo.add(info3);
        listInfo.add(info4);

        // filter 1: less date - group by max date by groupId
        List<Info> listResult = new ArrayList<>(listInfo.stream()
                .filter(info -> info.getDate().getTime() < date.getTime())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Info::getGroupId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.reducing((Info i1, Info i2) -> i1.getDate().getTime() > i2.getDate().getTime() ? i1 : i2),
                        Optional::get))).values());

        // filter 2: more date - nothing change in list
        List<Info> listMoreByDate = listInfo.stream()
                .filter(info -> info.getDate().getTime() >= date.getTime())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        listResult.addAll(listMoreByDate);

        System.out.println("result: " + listResult);
    }

    private static Date getDateFromStr(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(dateStr);
    }
}

class Info {
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private Long groupId;

    public Info(Long id, Date date, Long groupId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Long getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(Long groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Info info = (Info) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, info.id) &&
                Objects.equals(date, info.date) &&
                Objects.equals(groupId, info.groupId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, date, groupId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Info{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", date=").append(date);
        sb.append(", groupId=").append(groupId);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no inherent virtue to a `Stream`; they should be used to make code easier to read. This might be a case where a for-loop is better than a stream.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can’t see anything simpler than

```
List<Info> listResult = Stream.concat(
    listInfo.stream()
        .filter(info -> info.getDate().getTime() < date.getTime())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Info::getGroupId, Function.identity(),
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Info::getDate))))
        .values().stream(),
    listInfo.stream()
        .filter(info -> info.getDate().getTime() >= date.getTime())
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

as these two operations are fundamentally different. Building a `Map` in the first step is unavoidable, as it will be used to identify the items with equal `getGroupId` property.

That said, you should consider switching from using `Date` to the `java.time` API.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can merge the two conditions by using the [partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) collector as follows:

```
 List<Info> resultSet = 
      listInfo.stream()
              .collect(collectingAndThen(partitioningBy(info -> info.getDate().getTime() < date.getTime()),
                     map -> Stream.concat(map.get(true)
                            .stream()
                            .collect(toMap(Info::getGroupId,
                                    Function.identity(),
                                    (Info i1, Info i2) -> i1.getDate().getTime() > i2.getDate().getTime() ? i1 : i2))
                            .values().stream(), map.get(false).stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))));
```

This essentially uses the `partitioningBy` collector to organise the elements in such a way that all the elements passing the criteria `info.getDate().getTime() < date.getTime()` aswell as where it's false i.e. where `info -> info.getDate().getTime() >= date.getTime()` is true into a `Map<Boolean, List<T>>`.

Further, we utilise the [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) collector to apply a finishing function upon the `Map<Boolean, List<T>>` returned by the `partitioningBy` collector, in this case we concatenate the result of the applying the logic of:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Info::getGroupId, 
          Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.reducing((Info i1, Info i2) -> i1.getDate().getTime() > i2.getDate().getTime() ? i1 : i2),
           Optional::get))))
.values();
```

which I've simplified to:

```
.collect(toMap(Info::getGroupId, Function.identity(), (Info i1, Info i2) -> i1.getDate().getTime() > i2.getDate().getTime() ? i1 : i2)))
.values();
```

with the elements returned where `info.getDate().getTime() < date.getTime()` returned false (`map.get(false).stream()`).

Finally, we collect the result into a `ArrayList` implementation with the [`toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) collector.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (even more verbose in definition but much less verbose at use site) is to create a custom [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html):

```
List<Info> listResult = listInfo.stream().collect(dateThresholdCollector(date));
```

where

```
private static Collector<Info, ?, List<Info>> dateThresholdCollector(Date date) {
    return Collector.of(
            () -> new ThresholdInfoAccumulator(date), ThresholdInfoAccumulator::accept,
            ThresholdInfoAccumulator::combine, ThresholdInfoAccumulator::addedInfos
    );
}
```

and

```
class ThresholdInfoAccumulator {

    private final Date date;
    private final List<Info> addedInfos = new ArrayList<>();

    ThresholdInfoAccumulator(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    List<Info> addedInfos() {
        return addedInfos;
    }

    ThresholdInfoAccumulator accept(Info newInfo) {
        if (canAdd(newInfo)) {
            addedInfos.add(newInfo);
        }
        return this;
    }

    boolean canAdd(Info newInfo) {
        if (newInfo.getDate().compareTo(date) < 0) { // lower date - max date by groupId
            return addedInfos.removeIf(addedInfo -> isEarlierDateInSameGroup(addedInfo, newInfo));
        }
        return true; // greater or equal date - no change
    }

    private boolean isEarlierDateInSameGroup(Info addedInfo, Info newInfo) {
        return addedInfo.getGroupId().equals(newInfo.getGroupId())
                && addedInfo.getDate().compareTo(newInfo.getDate()) < 0;
    }

    ThresholdInfoAccumulator combine(ThresholdInfoAccumulator other) {
        other.addedInfos().forEach(this::accept);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Note: it won't be that effective if you have huge number of groups/infos because it does *not* group by `getGroupId` (it iterates the entire list for every `Info` to be added).